# R Why False results when using the function "mean with condition" at period.apply

Tags: r, function, statistics, apply, xts

I want to calculate the average value for values above a constant every year.

I explain with this example:

```
library(xts) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec) 
head(edhec)

edhec_4yr <- edhec["1997/2001"] 
ep <- endpoints(edhec_4yr, "years")

# mean 
period.apply(edhec_4yr, INDEX = ep, function(x) apply(x,2,mean))

# Length with condition Ok

period.apply(edhec_4yr, 
             INDEX = ep, 
             function(x) apply(x,
                               2, 
                               function(y) length(which(y>0.002))))


# But Mean with condition : the results are false, 
#they do not correspond to the true results. Why!!!

period.apply(edhec_4yr, 
             INDEX = ep, 
             function(x) apply(x,
                               2, 
                               function(y) mean(which(y>0.002))))

View(edhec_4yr)
```

Thank you in advance for explain me why I do not find a good result in the last step!

Comment: your code works fro me, `R version 3.3.3` and `PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but does it give the true average value when y> 0.002

Comment: For me the results make this :   exp. Convertible Arbitrage mean (when >0.002) = 6.090909 for year 1997.   it's false!!! Can you Eric Fail  give me your results please!

Comment: You kinda lost me. I don't know if it's _true_ as such, but I ran your code and it worked. Maybe you could elaborate what the issue is?

Comment: I know that the code works but I explained above that it gives a false results!  " the results are false, they do not correspond to the true results. Why!!!

Comment: Can you repeat to me how you know thy are _false_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help you debug your issue if you create simple examples. A simple example makes the problem clear:

```
set.seed(21)
(x <- rnorm(10))
# [1]  0.793013171  0.522251264  1.746222241 -1.271336123  2.197389533
# [6]  0.433130777 -1.570199630 -0.934905667  0.063493345 -0.002393336
x > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
which(x > 0)
# [1] 1 2 3 5 6 9
mean(which(x > 0))
# [1] 4.333333
```

So you need something like this:

```
apply.yearly(edhec_4yr, function(x) apply(x, 2, function(y) mean(y[y > 0.002])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua Ulrich. From your example I understood well, my first function calculates the average of the rank and not the true parameter value. thanks again

Comment: @tazrart: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).